# Displaying delimited text to a listview in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a text file(location stored in destination in program) I want to read the data line by line and write it to the list view. List View has three columns.

**TextFile**

Hello*How are you*I am

olleh*uoy era woh*ma I

**Output in list view**

Hello | How are you | I am

olleh| uoy era woh |ma I

**File Name:Program.cs**

```
public void read(string destination)
    {
        StreamReader sw = File.OpenText(destination);
        string s = "";
        while ((s = sw.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] words = s.Split('*');
            foreach(string word in words)
            {
              // i have no idea how to send it to the list view 

            }
        }
        sw.Close();
   }
```

**File Name: Form1.cs**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
           lvi.SubItems.Add();
           lvi.SubItems.Add();
           listview1.Items.Add(li);
         }
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? Why don't simply add appropriate item to the listview like you've shown in your second snippet? Of course, you have to move `read` method to `Form1` class in this case in order to be able to add items to listview easily.

Answer (score 1):

Add your words to list

```
  List<string> wordslist=new List<string>();//global declaration 
    while ((s = sw.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] words = s.Split('*');
                foreach(string word in words)
                {
                 wordslist.Add(word);
                }
            }
```

then loop to fill data in list view

```
for(int i=0;i<wordslist.Count-2;i+=3)
{
           lvi.SubItems.Add(i);
           lvi.SubItems.Add(i+1);
           lvi.SubItems.Add(i+2);
           listview1.Items.Add(li);
}
```